# What features of HTML5 can I use right now?

Tags: html

Any suggestions which feature can I use for simple web pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use new HTML5 tags which make markup more semantic. In order to get started right away, use this [Initializr - HTML5 templates generator](http://www.initializr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how advanced you plan on making your website. Generally speaking most of the real browsers (NOT IE) support most of the html 5 elements.

Have a look at `http://html5readiness.com/` to see what elements are supported by which browsers.

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com is specifically designed to answer your question.